# How do I disable Two-Factor Authentication properly?

Tags: frontend, frontend-error

I've just installed Magento and tried to log into it as an admin. However, the Two-Factor Authentication message showed up:

[image]

After a bit of looking up, I decided to disable the Two-Factor Authentication by setting

> 'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0

in xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/etc/config.php and then run 'php bin/magento s:up' command.

After that, I tried to access my site and this was what I got:

[image]

What had gone wrong and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Please run the following command, and the site will be up. The website is broken because you have not deployed static content.**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```

> **And if you are using the latest version of Magento, please disable the module using the command below:**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Thank you significantly!

Comment: Yep this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands in magento root

```
php bin/magento mo:d Magento_TwoFactorAuth;
rm -rf var/ generated/;
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:d:c;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
php bin/magento c:f;
```

Comment: I followed your guide and the site frontend showed up again. However, when I access /admin, fill in my username and password, nothing happened. I still couldn't log in as an admin. Why was that?

Comment: Now go into root generated folder and check metadata folder is generated or not. if it's generated then delete it and then try to relogin.

Comment: I tried 'php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth' and now I can log into my site as an admin. Still, your method helped me fix the broken frontend. Thank you!

Comment: Ok that's amazing , If it's resolved then like and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. After disabling the module click **logout** and clear your browser cache and after that try to login.
2. And for the design is not loading is because you run the command **setup:upgrade** but didn't run the **setup:static-content:deploy -f** command, please run all the command and after that this should work

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Run the following command in Magento Root

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth;
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
```